# Exclude active record set from another recordset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to exclude the results of recordset #1 from recordset #2 in Rails 3 or 4, Activerecord?

I have tried this before with ugly code trying to remove the id's by adding them to a hash and excluding them from the query.

Must be a clean way to remove certain id's or results from a recordset?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17560591/276959

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails ActiveRecord: Find All Users Except Current User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672744/rails-activerecord-find-all-users-except-current-user)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can perform a negative `where` like this:

```
Post.where.not(author: author)
```

Taken from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions