# Except in rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code:

```
  @note = @patient.notes.find(params[:id])
  @notes = @patient.notes.where(jahr: @note.jahr, quartal: @note.quartal).except(@note)
```

Somehow the `.except(@note)` is not working, i get no error, but `@note` is still contained in `@notes` What do i wrong? Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at the generated DB query ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672744/rails-activerecord-find-all-users-except-current-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`except` is used to skip parts of your query, as in `.except(:where)` to skip the `where` clause. You might want to use something like `.where('notes.id != ?', @note.id)` instead. Or in Rails 4, `where.not`.