# Adding a scope to a has_many through association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, scopes

I have a `Project` and `User` models joined by a `Membership` model. I want to retrieve a project's members except one user.

```
project.members.where.not(id: current_user)
```

[Like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17560591/276959), I want to use a scope:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :except, ->(user) { where.not(id: user) }
end
```

But this doesn't work.

```
p.members.except(User.find(1))
User Load (1.0ms)
  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

User Load (0.4ms)
  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "users"."id" = "memberships"."user_id"
  WHERE "memberships"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 2]]
```

As you can see this results in two queries, not one. And returns all the members, not taking into account the exclusion.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I think the scope you are looking for should be on the membership model.  It would be helpful if you added the other class definitions and perhaps the columns in the membership table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the scope to something else, like **except_for** or **all_except**. Name except is already used by active_record

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-except

Also you get 2 queries because you are doing User.find(1) which results in the first query.