# How to make a scope that shows ALL categories except ONE

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show photos with categories from 1-9, but NOT show photos with category 15.

I tried:

```
scope :no_landing, ->  {where(category_id: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])}
```

But there has to be a more efficient way.

Any ideas?

Thanks guys!

Comment: `where.not(category_id: 15)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails ActiveRecord: Find All Users Except Current User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672744/rails-activerecord-find-all-users-except-current-user/17560591#17560591)

Comment: To add to @RocketR, you want to pass an id to the scope: `scope :no_landing, ->(id) { where.not(category_id: id) }` [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672744/rails-activerecord-find-all-users-except-current-user/17560591#17560591) out for more details.