# RoR Filter Out Current User with Join, Select and Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have the following statement in an RoR controller called nominations:

```
@users = User.joins(:department).select("CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name, 
   ' - ', name) as user_dept, last_name, first_name, name, 
   users.id").order("last_name, first_name, middle_name")
```

In the view, I have this to put this in a drop down:

```
<%= select_tag "nomination[user_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 
     :id, :user_dept), prompt: "Select User" %>
```

I want to filter out the current user so that someone can't nominate themselves.  I've seen several articles about using where.not or scope [(for example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672744/rails-activerecord-find-all-users-except-current-user) but all of the statements I could find are basic selections from one table.  How do I define and use a scope while preserving all of the other stuff?  I need that join and formatting.

**Edit** - Whenever I try where.not anywhere in the controller or model, I get the error "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)".

Comment: If your Rails version is lower than 4, then `where.not` won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
@users = ...
@users = @users.where.not(users: {id: current_user.id})
```

Note that you need to specify name of the table (not the model) when you do the join, otherwise database will have no idea which id column it should look for (`users.id` vs `departments.id`).

### Before Rails 4

`not` method is quite a new thing and is not available in Rails 3. (In fact, where method wasn't expecting to be called without arguments, that's why the error you got is `unexpected number of arguments (0 for 1)`).

Those were dark times when we had to use the following monstrosity to get stuff  working:

```
@users = ...
@users = @users.where('users.id != ?', current_user.id)
```

Comment: I've tried where.not but it results in "undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass".  I'm going to assume this is because this site is not running Rails 4?

Comment: @BigEMPin - You would get different error. Reason is I mispelled your instance variable name. :P Fixed now.

Comment: Actually, sorry...that threw me off too.  This is the error I was getting before when I was trying where.not: "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1). This occurred after I changed user to users."

Comment: That's the error I would expect if you are not running Rails 4. :) Will update answer in a second

Comment: Actually tried that just as you were posting the answer...worked so I'll give it to you.  I think when I tried that before, I misworded something.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a scope in the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :except_id, -> (id) ( where.not(id: id) )
end
```

Then you can freely use it everywhere you want:

```
@users = User.except_id(current_user.id).joins(:department).select("...")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @users = User.where.not(id: current_user.id).joins(:department)
.select("CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name, ' - ', name) as user_dept, last_name, first_name, name, users.id")
.order("last_name, first_name, middle_name")
```