# Filter ActiveRecord for current user using devise where > 1 user tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an app with 2 user tables: `User` and `Trainer` (everyone is a `User`, and a small subset of `User`s are also `Trainer`s).

I'm using devise.

I think we can filter based on `User` [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749008/5783745)

```
User.where(user: {id: current_user.id})
```

Can we somehow do the same (filtering for the `current_user`) but in the `Trainer` model?

Note: to make matters slightly *more* complicated, what I'm actually trying to retrieve are all of the `Availability` slots for a `Trainer` (where `Trainer` belongs_to `User` and `Trainer` has_many `Availabilities`)

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You should probably show your `Trainer` model. But, it seems likely you're looking for something like:

```
Trainer.find_by(user: current_user).availabilities
```

Or, perhaps, just:

```
current_user.trainer.availabilities
```

I'm not sure what this is meant to be:

```
Users.where(users: {id: current_user.id})
```

...but it looks wrong in a number of ways.

Comment: Ah I tried the simplify the code from the related question (but messed it up; I'll fix it). Here's what Trainer looks like: `Trainer.column_names
=> ["id", "user_id", "first_name", "last_name", "description" .. ]`