# how to create line chart and appear data in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I have column called `speed` in table `Gspeed`. I need to create a line chart `group by minute (created_at)` and point appear `speed`.

For example `p1 (110.4)` , `p2 (113.5)`, and more.

There can be many values of speed.

I have two models: user and Gspeed. Gspeed contains `name` type `string` , `speed` type `float`.

Example of database:

[image: db image]

> appear speed for only current user

Example of shape

[image: image of chart]

when try with code in controller 
 `@line_chart_data =Gspeed.all.group_by_minute(:created_at).average(:speed)`

in view

> appear only value

[image: shape]

Comment: The topic seems interesting, but to get help from people maybe you want to improve your question with some details about models, xy axis, sample data and what you tried so far.

Comment: add more information Thanks iGian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this can fit your request. Maybe you need to manipulate further the array of data.

Build in the controller the set of data (I used average, but it's up to you):

```
@line_chart_data = User.all.map { |user|
    {name: user.name, data: user.gspeeds.group_by_minute(:created_at).average(:speed)}
    }
```

Then draw the graph in the view:

```
<%= line_chart @line_chart_data %>
```

Comment: Thanks for response but have some error `undefined method group_by_minute' for 130.5:Float`

Comment: Do you have `gem 'groupdate'` in your Gem file? Does this code `Gspeed.all.group_by_minute(:created_at)` raise some error?

Comment: when change to `@line_chart_data = Gspeed.all.group_by_minute(:created_at).average(:speed)
` appear one value only updated on description question

Comment: I hope to view output Thanks iGian

Comment: `Gspeed.all.group_by_minute(:created_at)` was just to test `group_by_minute`, not send to chartikick. I can see output, so you should: the code in my answer should work also for you. If not maybe I'm missing some piece of information. Try print the `@line_chart_data` array, check if any data is in. Of course, I suppose you set up relations between models and database contains some sample data.

Comment: Thanks IGian  yes work for my but draw one value only . yes setup relation between models  `belongs_to :user, :optional => true` in `Gspeed model`  &   `has_many :gspeed` in `user model`

Comment: Weird. Can you please try this `<%= User.last.gspeeds.inspect %>` in your view? Does it print anything?

Comment: yes this output `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Speed id: 8, name: "#431", speed: 130, created_at: "2018-06-18 10:11:22", updated_at: "2018-06-18 10:11:22", user_id: 1>, #<Speed id: 9, name: "#431", speed: 120, created_at: "2018-06-18 10:11:22", updated_at: "2018-06-18 10:11:22", user_id: 1>, #<Speed id: 10, name: "#431", speed: 110, created_at: "2018-06-18 10:11:22", updated_at: "2018-06-18 10:11:22", user_id: 1>` and some of data

Comment: @user9773555, Looking at your output I can gather: **1-** you have only one user (the last has `id=1`), this will draw just one line; **2-** the table name is not `Gspeed` but `Speed` (not a problem at all, just change my code to match your nomenclature); **3**- all records in `Speed` are created at the exact same time (`created_at: "2018-06-18 10:11:22")`, that's why you have only one point. -- **Solution:** use Rails console to add manually more points for user 1 (wait one minute between each Speed.save) ant add a new user ant his speeds. Then you should see the lines.

Comment: use seed.rb for add data and wait one minute but appear one value only @iGian

Comment: after add another user and some data appear series two and only one value again

Comment: can appear all but current_user ?

Comment:  Glad you solved. For excluding current user, instead of `User.all` look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672744/rails-activerecord-find-all-users-except-current-user

Comment: yes Thanks you ! i convert to mad. I can't believe that the problem solved. thanks you